# Split result not usable on android

Tags: java, android, string, split, string-table

I have a string that I split, it works perfectly until i want to use it : when I use a 'for' to read what a have in my String table I shows exactly what I want, but when I use if(MyStringTable[1] == "a") it isn't true, even though I just saw that MyStringTable[1] was equal to "a".
My string table is "static" declared.
I'm wondering if there is an invisible character or something that has been created with the split.

Comment: try to used string `.equals()` or `.equalsignorecase()` for string equality checking

Comment: NExt time, post your code as well-  this was an easy guess, but for a harder problem  we're not going to get it without code to debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of `String`s, use `.equals()` in order to check if a `String` is equal to another. If one of them is a character, cast it previously to a `String` using `.toString()` to make it match this approach.

Comment: I said "a" for the exemple, it's actually a string of 5 characters.

Comment: Same goes for that example, if it's an array of characters, simply declare a new `String` via: `String myNewString = new String(characterArray)`.

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped you (and also regarding to your future questions), you should accept the question that helped you most, you can do this by choosing the 'tick' under the points of the answer you want to accept. This will help other users to know this is the question that helped you and also will help for reputation.